# If a Service is stopped, what happens to background threads?

Tags: android, service, android-widget

If I have an Android Service which, in `onStartCommand`, has the following:

```
MyWidgetUpdater updater = new MyWidgetUpdater();
updater.updateWidgets(...);
```

The `updater` retrieves data in a background thread and then updates the widget(s) on the foreground thread.  What happens if the service is stopped (e.g. `stopSelf()`) before the background processing is complete?  Will this cause the widgets to sometimes not complete their update (as the thread is presumably killed)?  If so, is there a design pattern to know when all of your widgets have completed updating and its safe to stop the service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens if the service is stopped (e.g. stopSelf()) before the background processing is complete?

Assuming that this is a thread you forked yourself, Android is oblivious to that thread, which will keep running, leaked, until Android terminates your process.

> If so, is there a design pattern to know when all of your widgets have completed updating and its safe to stop the service?

Don't call `stopSelf()` until the work is completed. I do not know where you are calling `stopSelf()`, but in the pattern you are citing, it would typically be done at the end of that thread.

This is one reason why `IntentService` is popular: it handles all the thread and `stopSelf()` stuff for you.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare.  To add more details, the background thread is kicked off using an ``AsyncTask``.  Will the ``onPostExecute()`` execute successfully if the service (which kicked off the ``AsyncTask``) is stopped?

Comment: Yes it will. But as CommonsWare pointed out, it would be better to either: use an IntentService, or stopSelf() at the end of your onPostExecute().

Comment: @ChrisKnight: "Will the onPostExecute() execute successfully if the service (which kicked off the AsyncTask) is stopped?" -- maybe. Your process can get terminated at any time, and is *far* more likely to be terminated when your service is destroyed. Hence, I agree with pcans: either use `IntentService`, or do not call `stopSelf()` until the end of `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Thanks both, will look into ``IntentService``.